# Flow for deleting Documentation examples could use improvements

Tags: bug, documentation

**The flow for deleting examples on Documentation has several practical issues**, including but possibly not limited to:

- Deletes of examples (even highly upvoted ones) can be requested by (just about?) anyone;
- A delete can be approved by a single user, possibly without rep limit(?);
- There seems to be no check about recreating an example with a title of a previously deleted one;
- There is no real good UI to see what happened, unless you *really* dig into the details;
- The link to a deleted example scrolls your browser all the way down to the example, but the "Rollback" button is (out of sight) all the way at the top;

**TLDR: Perhaps some changes are in order here?**

---

Here's an example demonstrating the above. I got triggered because of a big drop in my reputation because of a deleted example with many upvotes (note I *don't* care about the rep, heck I'd prefer if there was none for Docs or not mixed with the main site...), and while investaging I saw:

1. The [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)'s "*Hello World*" topic's "*Using window.alert()*" example was requested to be deleted at `2016-07-26 09:31:21Z`, and afterwards approved by a user at unknown moment:

   [image: screenshot of deletion UI]
2. It was subsequently recreated at `2016-07-27 07:22:40Z` in (IMHO inferior) form like this:

   [image: recreated UI]
3. And after that an edit was suggested at `2016-07-27 07:25:16Z` which reconstructs the original version but as an *edit to the new* example. It even was rejected as "often" as it was approved (once). Here's a screenshot:

   [image: recreation of the topic]

   The full side note or history of what happened only became clear to me at screenshot 3, and only because I wanted to be thorough in my meta question: otherwise I would've never found out what had happened.

   The "new" version of this example has 2 upvotes, so the example sits way too low as far as the community seemed concerned (since it had 20+ upvotes in its original form).

   Now again, I don't care (!) for rep from Documentation, but: *if* you decide to hand it out, the above example seems rather unfair for editors of the original example.

The above example (sorry for the pun!) of how all this works is not very important. I doubt many people care about yet another JS hello-world. But on more important examples / topics this *could* be a problem, and perhaps some improvements can be made?

---

Addendums:

- When I clicked the "-X reputation" link I see this message:

  > Linked example has been **deleted**; [view prior to deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/719/using-window-alert?asOf=20160726130654723).

  Following that link you get taken to a page that scrolls your browser to the deleted example, but (way out of sight) at the *top* is a button to roll back:

  [image: deleted example view]

Comment: related problem: topic deletion doesn't get canceled once a new example gets added to that topic. It should probably lock the topic once a deletion request gets submitted.

Comment: When was the original topic still there? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: @JF Good question. I added an addendum at the end with additional info on that. You actually helped me find the "rollback" button which I'd sworn I'd seen but couldn't find when posting the meta question.

Comment: Seems quite a few of these problems are a *consequence* of the unit of work for edits being the entire topic, not individual examples. Thought I saw some meta questions on that go by recently as well...